# website (or app) for review presentation/conferences

Tags: presentation

I watch a lot of video presentations and I have option to see some live presentations as well. I want to make list of favorite presentation and I want to leave feedback. Did anyone know website (or app) where I can see look for presentations, search by topic/programming language/people and I can leave review or comment? I'm looking for something similar to imbd for presentations.

Answer (score 0):

This website is for programming questions. What you are asking is entirely off-topic. But the website you are looking for called [SlideShare](http://www.slideshare.net/).

Comment: @user7283346 Thanks, so where I should ask about it? Is there any other 'stack' community that should ask this question?